# How to refresh a single item in a FlatList in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I made a Like function with React and Flask API, it works pretty well, it makes the Like action but it only appears when I refresh the whole list. Somehow I want to refresh the Like picture and the Like count at the post.

I tried to put extraData in my FlatList but that does not solve my problem...

```
handleClick() {
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': 'jwt ' + this.props.jwt
    };
    const action = this.props.has_liked?  'unlike':'like' 
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/API/likeaction",{
        id: this.props.id,
        action: action
    }, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
    this.setState({liked: action})
  }
    render() {
      const img = this.props.has_liked?  require('../assets/icons/heart-filled.png') : require('../assets/icons/heart-no-fill.png') 
        return(
        <View style={{flex:1, marginTop: 10, marginBottom:16, left: 20}}>
         <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}> 
         <Image source={this.props.image_uri} style={{height:42, width: 42, borderRadius:21}}/>
          <Text style={{left:20,paddingTop:6}}>{this.props.author}</Text>
          <Text style={{position: 'absolute', right: 40, paddingTop:6,fontSize:12,color:'#babbbc'}}> {this.props.date} </Text>
         </View>
        <View style={{flex:1, left: 60, right:20,width: '70%', marginTop:-10}}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18,marginBottom:6}}>{this.props.title} </Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:16,marginBottom:6 }}>{this.props.content}</Text>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
          <Image style={{width:24, height:24, marginBottom:6, marginTop:6}} source={img} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{paddingTop:10, marginLeft:6, fontSize:14,color:'#bfbfbf'}}>{this.props.likes}</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      );
    }

  }
```

```
<FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            extraData={this.state}
            renderItem={({item}) => <PostView title={item.title}
                                        content={item.content}
                                        author={item.author} 
                                        date={item.date_posted} 
                                        likes={item.likes} 
                                        has_liked={item.has_liked}
                                        jwt = {this.props.screenProps.jwt}
                                        id = {item.id}
                                        image_uri={{uri:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/profile_pics/'+item.profile_image}}/> }
                                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                                        onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with in home

```
this.state = {
        loading: true,
        email: '',
        error: '',
        refreshing: false,
        dataSource: [],
        updated: false
      }



handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({ updated: true })
    }



handleRefresh = () => {
 this.setState({
   refreshing: true,
   data: this.state.dataSource
  }, () => {
    this.makeRemoteRequest()
   })
        }
```

Replace

```
<PostView title={item.title}
.... 
/>
```

with

```
<PostView title={item.title}
    .....
    handleChange={this.handleChange}/>






    extraData={this.state}

and update
```

and

```
  handleClick() {
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': 'jwt ' + this.props.jwt
    };
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/API/likeaction",{
        id: this.props.id,
    }, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      if(response.data.account == "liked"){
        this.setState({liked:true})
      }else{
        this.setState({liked:false})
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

with

```
handleClick() {
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': 'jwt ' + this.props.jwt
    };
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/API/likeaction",{
        id: this.props.id,
    }, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.props.handleChange(true);
      if(response.data.account == "liked"){
        this.setState({liked:true})
      }else{
        this.setState({liked:false})
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }


const img = this.state.liked?  require('../assets/icons/heart-filled.png') : require('../assets/icons/heart-no-fill.png')
```

with

```
const img = this.state.liked ?  require('../assets/icons/heart-filled.png') : require('../assets/icons/heart-no-fill.png')
```

Comment: It does not work only when I refresh the whole table :/

Comment: Still nothing, somehow It does not recognize changes in the data

Comment: I did! still nothing, it drives me crazy. the like count is still frozen until I pull to refresh.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded the 2 related files. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!!! https://github.com/mrkkrly/morzsa

Comment: I changed everything and still nothing :/

Comment: Not working :(((( I get these two messages when I start the simulator, I dunno if theye are related:arning: Failed child context type: Invalid child context `virtualizedCell.cellKey` of type `number` supplied to `CellRenderer`,  ////// 'Warning: Can\'t perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s', 'the componentWillUnmount method',

Comment: I changed componentDidMount to componentWillUpdate and it does the refresh but wont mount the data at start

Answer (score 1):

extraData :

```
extraData={{this.state}}
```

and put `this.setState({liked: action})` here:

```
.then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({liked: action})
    })
```